# Can I include extra columns in a m->m mapping table?

Tags: mysql, schema, foreign-key, clustered-primary-key

I guess this is sort of an odd question, but consider this scenario.

```
table classes (id_pk)
table students (id_pk)
table students_classes_map (students_id_fk_pk, classes_id_fk_pk, finalExamScore decimal, finalGrade decimal ...)
```

I am using unique combinations of foreign keys to map students to all classes that they ever took. Standard practice. But, say that I wanted to store some statistics for students and their classes, statistics that didn't change after a class ended.

Is what I did ok practice or should map tables simply map m2m relations and not include any other columns? I.e. should I create a new table called player_classes with an autoinc int pk as a one to many table that holds some data for a user in a particular class? (Grade, attendance, etc) and separate this data from the student_class_map table

Comment: I would look at this in the following sense. A student_class_map (or student_class_timetable) should be about lecture/lab locations and times (and/or attendance). You could have another table called student_class_grade which could be all the grades ever obtained by all of the students. Most of the time (and I did say most) you will **either** be interested in grades **or** in locations and/or attendance so you'll **either** be joining with one table **or** the other, reducing potential overhead.